# Undo the effect of takeUntil on trigger of another action in rxjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am using `redux-observables` to handle effects for my react/redux app. I am facing a situation where I want to undo the effect of `takeUntil` when I trigger a redux action.

Here is a sample code

```
const productOrderPlace = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(action.PRODUCT_ORDER_PLACE),
    mergeMap(() => {
      return api.productOrderPlace(state$.value).pipe(mergeMap((res) => {
        return merge(of(action.getStatus()).pipe(delay(res.beginAt)), of(action.getStatusExpired()).pipe(delay(15000)))
      }));
    })
  );
};

const getStatus = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(action.GET_STATUS),
    takeUntil(merge(
      action$.pipe(ofType(actions.GET_STATUS_EXPIRED)),
      action$.pipe(ofType(actions.GET_STATUS_DONE))
    )),
    mergeMap(() => {
      return api.getStatus(state$.value).pipe(mergeMap(() => {
       // this is the polling call here i would be triggering GET_STATUS again after a specific interval from the current polling response  or call GET_STATUS_DONE if response contains success status
      }));
    })
  );
}
```

So, basically what I am doing is when user clicks on Order button , `productOrderPlace`  API will be called and then start polling for the order status by calling `getStatus`, here for polling i am not using the default recipe from rxjs with interval or timer because, the polling interval is not same, the next polling interval will be taken from previous polling response. And the first polling call should be called after some seconds based on `beginAt` in `productOrderPlace` response. And the maximum time user can wait is 15 seconds, so I start a timer as soon as I get `productOrderPlace` response

So, now I am facing a issue, when expired event is triggered , user is shown error. However, user can again click on Order button and place the order again, in such case `getStatus` wont be executed because I have used `takeUntil` and the action inside `takeUntil` is already trigger , so I wanted to undo the effect of takeUntil when user clicks Order button again (i.e when PRODUCT_ORDER_PLACE is triggered again)

Comment: Where does the polling start? i dont understand how your two functions use each other

Comment: why is productOrderPlace calling itself but with only one argument?

Comment: @Jensen it's actually api.productOrderPlace , it is not the same function , I have made few changes when I posted it here because I don't want to leave my company code in public forum, might case violation, but this code is the overall gist of what I am trying. Have edited the code above. And polling is not a explicit one, I have mentioned in the comment that I call GET_STATUS again based on the status from API . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a way to solve it:

```js
const getStatus = (action$, state$) => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType(action.GET_STATUS),

    mergeMap(() => {
      return api.getStatus(state$.value).pipe(mergeMap(() => {/* ... */}));
    }),

    // Placing the `takeUntil` operator here since the `mergeMap` operator
    // won't pass along the *complete* notification unless all of the active
    // inner observables complete too.
    takeUntil(
      action$.pipe(
        ofType(action.PRODUCT_ORDER_PLACE),
        switchMap(
          () => merge(
            action$.pipe(ofType(actions.GET_STATUS_EXPIRED)),
            action$.pipe(ofType(actions.GET_STATUS_DONE))
          )
        )
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

By using `switchMap`, we **resubscribe** each time the `PRODUCT_ORDER_PLACE` action is emitted.